# All possible combinations from a set with replacement alternatives

Tags: java, replace, set, combinations

I need an algorithm written in java to calculate the following:

Given a set S = {s1,s2,...,sn} with n elements denoting types and sets s1_alternatives ={s1a,s1b,...,s1z} , s2_alternatives ={s2a,s2b,...,s2z},..., sn_alternatives = {sna,snb,...,snz},

calculate all possible combinations for set S set by replacing its elements with alternative elements of sets s1_alternatives, s2_alternatives,...,sn_alternatives.

Example: Given S = {a,b,c} and sets of alternatives a_alternatives = {a1,a2,a3}, b_alternatives = {b1,b2}, c_alternatives = {c1,c2}. Some possible combinations of the elements of S with their alternatives are S_ALTERNATIVES = {{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b1,c1},{a3,b1,c2},...}.

I am looking for a solution written in java that can be applied on any set (of any object type and not restricted to strings) of arbitrary size.

I have tried this code, but I need proper stopping conditions for the recursion at proper places. I get only 5 combination sets out of 12!:

combination: the set from which all combinations must be built

type2Words: all replacement alternatives

getType: gives the type of a given element

result: possible sets of all combinations

```
void calculateAllCombinations(Set<String> combination,
Map<String, Set<String>> type2Words, Map<String,String> getType,
Set<Set<String>>result)
{   
  Set<String> wordOfStartCombination = new HashSet<String>(combination);

  for(String wordPlaceHolder:wordOfStartCombination)
  {
     String type = getType.get(wordPlaceHolder);
     Set<String> allWithThisType = type2Words.get(type);

     for(String thisType:allWithThisType)
     {
        Set<String> wordTemp = new HashSet<String>(combination);
        wordTemp.remove(wordPlaceHolder);
        wordTemp.add(thisType);
        result.add(wordTemp);
        if(!result.contains(wordTemp))
           calculateAllCombinations(wordTemp,type2Words,getType,result);
     }          
   }
 }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Set<String> startCombination = new HashSet<String>();
    startCombination.add("a1");startCombination.add("b1"); startCombination.add("c1");


    Map<String,String> getType = new HashMap<String, String>();
    getType.put("a1", "type_a");
    getType.put("a2", "type_a");
    getType.put("a3", "type_a");
    getType.put("b1", "type_b");
    getType.put("b2", "type_b");
    getType.put("c1", "type_c");
    getType.put("c2", "type_c");
    Map<String,Set<String>> type2Word = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    Set<String> typedSet1 = new HashSet<String>();
    typedSet1.add("a1");typedSet1.add("a2");typedSet1.add("a3");type2Word.put("type_a", typedSet1);

    Set<String> typedSet2 = new HashSet<String>();
    typedSet2.add("b1");typedSet2.add("b2");type2Word.put("type_b", typedSet2);

    Set<String> typedSet3 = new HashSet<String>();
    typedSet3.add("c1");typedSet3.add("c2");type2Word.put("type_c", typedSet3);

    Set<Set<String>> result = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
    result.add(startCombination);   

    calculateAllCombinations(startCombination,type2Word,getType,result);
    for(Set<String> word:result)
        System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: so the all combinations of {a,b,c} from ur example will be {{a1,b1,c1},{a1,b1,c2},{a1,b2,c1},{a1,b2,c2},{a2,b1,c1},{a2,b1,c2},{a2,b2,c1},{a2,b2,c2},{a3,b1,c1},{a3,b1,c2},{a3,b2,c1},{a3,b2,c2}} ?

Comment: it is simple task, it can be done with or without recursion, now im going sleep(about 8 hours :) ), and if no one answer then i'll do then.

Comment: indeed. I solved the problem by adding an additional condition in the inner for loop to perform wordTemp.add(thisType), if (!wordPlaceHolder.equals(thisType)). Thank you though for your answers :-)